# Google "Brand Account" can not access associated "Google Drive"

Tags: drive

I recently set up a Brand Account on Google for a non-profit organization I am affiliated with. I have been unable to get to the account's Drive, even though under My Account (for the Brand Account) it tells me I have 0 bytes used. Every attempt to get the the drive kicks me over to my personal account.

I heard from one fellow on the Google My Business forum. He suspects that the Drive functionality for Brand Accounts may be intentionally deprecated.

It seems perhaps they are steering the branded accounts more to just social stuff (Youtube, Pictures, Google+ seem fully functional).

Can anyone here verify or disprove this theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that google Brand Accounts do not support Drive. Too bad, it would have been a great solution to our needs.